# Selecting parents in tournament selection

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I'm writing up a GA and I'm not sure if when selecting the parents I'm suppose to loop through my population finding each a parent using tournament selection or if I'm meant to find two parents using tourament selection for each solution in my population.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not too clear what you mean to be the difference between your suggested alternatives, but generally, the way it works is that you pick two random individuals, keep the best one, and that becomes Parent #1. Then you pick two more random individuals, keep the best one, and it becomes Parent #2. Those two parents then recombine to produce offspring which go into the child population. Repeat until you have enough offspring.

So you generate a child population using something like the following loop. (You may generate multiple offspring per set of parents...adjust the loop bounds to fit your situation).

```
for i = 1 to N 
    pick individual t1 at random from parent population
    pick individual t2 at random from parent population
    parent1 = winner(t1, t2)

    pick individual t1 at random from parent population
    pick individual t2 at random from parent population
    parent2 = winner(t1, t2)

    generate offspring from parent1, parent2
    mutate offspring
    evaluate offspring
    add offspring to child population
end for
```

Comment: Thanks.
Does this mean that sometimes you will crossover the same parents?
It's also worth adding that the tournament size doesn't have to be limited to two. You can select as many random parents as you like and find the fittest.

Comment: If you cross a parent with itself, you're obviously going to get a clone of the original, along with some typical chance of mutations.  It's a judgement call, I guess, but I wouldn't, because if you have one or two members that are much fitter than all the others, you can kill your diversity fairly quickly.

Comment: And I often reserve the top one or two members of a generation to be cloned anyway.  I don't want that happening by accident, in addition to my reservation.

Comment: Traditionally, you don't worry about it. It happens with fairly low probability, and you just  let it happen. However, you can sometimes get better results with some sort of incest prevention (it's worth pointing out that you're spending some of your search effort looking for duplicates now, so it might actually hurt you too).

Look at the CHC genetic algorithm for an example of a very clever way of incorporating incest prevention. Unfortunately, I don't think the original paper by Eshelman is available in digital form, but you can find descriptions of the algorithm online.

Comment: @Novak What you are describing is usually known as Elitism (The guaranteeing of 1 or N best individuals to be propogated to the next generation).